# How can I loop a video back to an existing part of the video?

Tags: html, video

Using this code, is there anyway I can manipulate "loop" to enable the video to loop back to the halfway point of the video?

```
<embed src="man.mov" width="320" height="320" loop="true"> </embed>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `<video>` tag of HTML5?

Comment: Would you know how to loop back to the middle of the video using that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the following code snippet and the `<video>` tag.

```
video.addEventListener('canplay', function(e) {
// this.volume = 0.4;
this.currentTime = 10; //this is the option you need
// this.play();
}, false);
```

The `video` tag will look like this

```
<video src="path/to/file" height=N width=N loop="loop"></video>
```

Comment: what should my in-line style say in loop?

Comment: @Matt, please consider reading any html documentation on topic `<video>`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I have the video looping, just not inside the video.

Comment: @Matt, `loop` option is used to make the video loop forever _from start to end_. Here you can work with JavaScript.